# between function and year variable in oracle

Tags: oracle

[I have a table T1 with 2 columns NAME & DT as shown in figure

```
 CREATE TABLE T1 ( NAME VARCHAR2(1), DT TIMESTAMP(3) );

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ( ‘A’ , TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2021-02-04 12:00:00.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’)); 

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ( ‘B’ , TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2021-02-05 12:00:00.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’)); 

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ( ‘C’ , TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2021-02-15 12:00:00.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’));
```

After executing above query, data gets populated and I want to select the records from DT from 1st jan till today of this year.

I have created a procedure as shown below such that if I run the same procedure next year, it needs to select the records from 1st jan till sysdate of that particular year i.e. here year changes..I have created a variable for the year and assigned current year to it..In next year, year variable will be 2022 etc..

How should I query it in WHERE clause to select the records from 1st Jan till sysdate of particular year (i.e. 2021/2022/2023 so on)..and you can see DT format is Timestamp

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P1
AS

     V_YEAR VARCHAR2(4); --  year  variable

     V_YEAR := TO_CHAR((SYSDATE), ‘YYYY);   -- Assigning current year to this variable

 BEGIN

      SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE DT BETWEEN TO_DATE(‘01/01/2021’, ‘mm/dd/yyyy’) AND TO_DATE(SYSDATE, ‘mm/dd/yyyy’);

END;
/]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKjGq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `trunc` in your query as follows:

```
DT BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YYYY') AND SYSDATE;
```

`TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YYYY')` returns the starting day of the year

Comment: So there is no need of year variable declaration and assigning current year to the variable right?   What if I need a records from 1st jan till the date I need..let us say till May 1st...How should I include that May 1st thing in where clause?

Comment: sysdate represents the current date.

Comment: I need the records from Jan 1st till May 1st of particular year (Each year I will execute this query)...How should I include the May 1st code part in where clause?

Comment: The May 1st will have different year right i.e. 2021/2022/2023...So I have included year variable in procedure

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option would be

`WHERE TRUNC(DT, 'YEAR') = TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR');`

If you wanted to get everything in the current year